# Look a Value in column and change in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
Name

foo
foo
bar
foo
bar
shoo
shoo
foo
bar
bar
```

I want to add the position of occurrence in the next column, something like **Serialized Name**

Expected Output:

```
Name    Serialized Name

foo      foo-1
foo      foo-2
bar      bar-1
foo      foo-3
bar      bar-2
shoo     shoo-1
shoo     shoo-2
foo      foo-4
bar      bar-3
bar      bar-4
```

My approach was to get the unique values of the column `list(df['Name'].unique())` and their count `list(df['Name'].value_counts())` but I am not exactly sure how to proceed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use, [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df["Serialized Name"] = (
    df['Name'] + "-" + (df.groupby("Name").cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
)
```

---

```
   Name Serialized Name
0   foo           foo-1
1   foo           foo-2
2   bar           bar-1
3   foo           foo-3
4   bar           bar-2
5  shoo          shoo-1
6  shoo          shoo-2
7   foo           foo-4
8   bar           bar-3
9   bar           bar-4
```

Comment: This works perfectly I used `df.insert(1, "Serialized Name", n)` to add it in the Dataframe where `n =  list(df['Name']  + "-" + (df.groupby("Name").cumcount() + 1).astype(str))`. 
But could add a little explanation ?

Comment: @RahulSharma, its straightforward groupby on ``Name`` and apply ``cumcount`` to get Number each item in each group from 0 to the length of that group - 1. Since start index is 0 we add +1, convert int to string so later it can be concated with ``Name`` column.

Answer (score -1):

This code will work

```
for i in df['Name'].unique():
  exec(f'{i}_count=0')

for i in range(len(df)):
  if df['Name'][i]=='foo':
    foo_count+=1
    df['Serialized Name'][i]=f'foo-{foo_count}'
  elif df['Name'][i]=='bar':
    bar_count+=1
    df['Serialized Name'][i]=f'bar-{bar_count}'
  else:
    shoo_count+=1
    df['Serialized Name'][i]=f'shoo-{shoo_count}'
```

Comment: You have just over-complicated a simple task & more-over ``foo, bar, shoo`` would be just samples & not actual data.